# Display: is it possible yet to collapse a set of non-custom data?

Tags: custom-fields

This is my first time on stack exchange so please excuse me if I've posted this in the wrong place, tagged it incorrectly, or missed anything else. And although I feel that I know civiCRM fairly well, I'm not at all a computer whiz, so forgive me if my tech language/terms aren't accurate. :)

Here goes... is it possible yet to collapse a set of built in/core fields, via the UI? I know how to do it for custom fields, but it'd be really helpful if I could do it for sets when I'm adding a contribution, for example.

I found this topic on the civiCRM Community Forum from 2012... 
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=26273.0

Sounds like Lobo thought it would be a good little project, but I haven't found any updates.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

UPDATE: Specifically, when recording a New Contribution, I'd like to collapse the Soft Credit fieldset, and expand the Additional Contribution Info fieldset. It would speed up my data entry if I didn't have to tab through the fields within Soft Credit or reach for my mouse to expand the Additional Contribution Info section.

Comment: Good first question :) Could you be a little more specific about what fields exactly you'd like to do this to? Maybe a screenshot of them?

Comment: What about your programming skills? Are you able to set up a little extension with a javascript file and collapse what you need to collapse?

Comment: Unfortunately my programming skills are non-existent. However... I do have a guy. I will pass your note onto him. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- The easiest one would be with css. But that would not be collapsing them, that would be hiding them. You just get the id's of the fields and hide them. If they are not required that just works.
- The 2nd easiest one would be with creating .extra.tpl files and doing it with jquery: https://civicrm.org/blogs/dave-greenberg/now-its-easier-add-custom-behaviors-templates. With jquery you should be able to make a collapsible fieldset.
- The most robust one would be with a custom extension and share with all of us on github http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension